# Pressure in a U-tube

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

In a U-shaped tube,if water is filled and pressure is equal in both arms,the pressure at the bottom is the same as in each arm. Why doesn't it add up?

Answer (score 1):

Water pressure increases with depth, not volume. At 1 meter deep the pressure will be the same in a small pool or a huge lake. It is the weight of the water above that presses down, not the amount of water to the sides.

Comment: In other words, the water at the surface and the water at the bottom of a column of water will be experiencing different pressures.